# Complexity description valid form using Big O notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) we should use Big O notation in the following manner:

`f(n) = O(g(x))`

where `=` is read not as "equals" but "is" instead.

So, it means that if algorithm has complexity for example `n^2 + 2n + 5` we should note it as:

`n^2 + 2n + 5 = O(n^2)`

But in some articles I saw that people note complexity as:

`O(n^2 + 2n + 5) = O(n^2)` instead

So is the latter expression is valid form or we can not note it in that way?

Comment: "some" articles = **vast majority of** articles = *correct notation*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, O(g(x)) is a set and it should be written with set notation, f(x) \in O(g(x)).

Authors, usually mention this and say that for simplicity we will use = for this.